# Double Router setup does not help hiding the computers behind it from each other

Tags: networking, router, security, home-networking, bridge-router

I have the following situation:

```
Router 1
  Computer 1
  Computer 2
  Computer 3

  Router 2
    Computer 4
```

`Computer 4` should not be accessible or visible to the other `Computer X`. But Computer 4 needs to be accessible over the internet.

Yet, they are accessible. `Router 2` is configured as a "Router" and not as a Repeater or Access Point.

`Computer 4` should be accessible over the internet, but NOT by other devices on the same network. The intention is added security for `Computer 4`.

That's it for the question, here's what is in my mind:

`Router 2` is so far connected over the LAN1 port. This probably makes it just act as a network switch, rather than having its own ecosystem. If I connect `Router 1` to `Router 2` over `Router 2`'s WAN port, I lose all connection to it and `Computer 4`, although that could potentially be my solution, right?

Answer (score 3):

It's really a matter of how "configurable" your router 2 is (and also router 1, more or less). The fact that router 2's LAN is a separate broadcast domain (when you use the **WAN** port to connect router 2 to router 1), and that the router has its own NAT, doesn't necessarily prevent the "outer" LAN hosts from being able to *initiate* communication / connection with it. All it takes is really a route on each of the "outer" hosts, or even, on router 1. (Certainly, the "inner" subnet is still more or less "hidden" anyway, as long as you don't have any route configure for it outside.)

With that said, most consumer grade routers these days have builtin firewall that filters "initiating" / "original" traffics from its WAN interface. In that case, `Computer 4` should indeed be getting some additional security. But in other words, if you want the outer hosts to be able to "actively" reach it, you'll need to bring down the firewall. (I mean, on these routers, often you only get to either have the firewall enabled or disabled as a whole.)

On more configurable routers (like one of those Linux-based "WRT" ones), you can customize the firewall to cater your specific needs.

P.S. There's also the alternative to port forward on router 2 so that its WAN IP (IOW its LAN IP in the "outer" LAN) would be referring to e.g. `Computer 4` for the forwarded port. Obviously, in this case you would not need any additional route outside. (On consumer grade routers, a port forwarding rule should implicitly configure whitelisting in the WAN-LAN filtering for the corresponding traffics.) To state the obvious, however, every outer host will be covered by the whitelisting, so if you want something like allowing certain traffics from only certain hosts to `Computer 4`, you'll still need a more "configurable" router.

Comment: Currently, the WAN port of Router 2 is being conntected to a LAN port from Router 1. But that did not work, so I connected Router 1 and 2 both over LAN ports, which essentially just increased the home network, but didn't add any security, right?

Comment: Yeah. Not sure what you mean by "did not work" though.

Comment: I lose all connections to the router 2 and computer 4.

Comment: @codepleb As I said, you'll need firewall down / customized on router 2 and a proper route on the "outside" to be able to connect to it. (An alternative is to port forward on router 2, which should implicitly add the desired exception on a socket (IP:port) basis and allows you to reach `Computer 4` with router 2's WAN IP.) As for "connection" to router 2, I assume you mean its admin portal. Often it is protected by the firewall as well so that it can only be reached from the LAN side (e.g. from `Computer 4`). Some router does have setting option that expose it for WAN side access though.

Comment: What I don't understand: Is it NEEDED to use the WAN port of Router 2, to have security gains? Meaning that if I just use the LAN ports as input from Router 1, I'll bypass all firewalls, etc? It's not that I have to use the WAN port because lack of ports... I just thought it might be specially protected or something.

Comment: @codepleb If you connect router 1 to router 2's LAN port instead, you are basically using only its builtin switch part (well, and the DHCP server, which you should disable in such setup anyway). Consumer grade routers, at least, usually do not have any L2 filtering (firewall) in its switch, and the L3 filtering only affects traffics going from one network (broadcast domain; BD) to another (i.e., in which case the router / gateway part is involved). And obviously you will lose the so-to-speak "isolation" (in terms of broadcast and multicast stuff) that comes inheritly with a separate LAN / BD.

Comment: Ok, so using the WAN port would be a must then, to not bypass all security measurements. I'll have to see if I get that to work. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

assuming these are both home-grade routers, perhaps of the exact same make and model, with the default configurations, then just connecting router 2's WAN port to a LAN port on router 1 could easily create two networks that are both using the same default 192.168.0.0/24 subnet. which would not work. check the lan settings of both routers to see what subnets they are using. change router2 to use a different LAN subnet than router 1. set router2's wan interface to a static IP inside of router1's subnet, and set its default gateway to router1's lan interface IP.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hope this considers that Computer 4 needs to be accessible from the internet (port forwarding, etc).

Comment: @codepleb It probably won't serve this goal very well given that often you can't customize the firewall on consumer grade router. If you bring down the firewall completely, it would be more or less pointless to keep such setup. If you double port forward, it might not work very well for all use cases.